# Using Domain mfp 8 server return "request time out" using real mobile device?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

[Image of the console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhM4C.png)

mobile apps are successfully connected using mfp server IP Address with port 9080 but using instead of IP with Domain the mfp8 server response error msg "The Request time out" and response text "undefined"

```
Using IP Address: mfpclient properties file: 
wlServerProtocol = http
wlServerHost = **.**.**.78
wlServerPort = 9080
wlServerContext = /mfp/
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions = png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
wlPlatformVersion = 8.0.0.00-20190910-142437
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = 
languagePreferences = en
wlBuildId = 8.0.0.00-20190910-142437
```

Using Domain: mfpclient properties file:

```
wlServerProtocol = https
wlServerHost = www.domainname.com
wlServerPort = 443
wlServerContext = /mfp/
testWebResourcesChecksum = false
ignoredFileExtensions = png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
wlPlatformVersion = 8.0.0.00-20190910-142437
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = 
languagePreferences = en
wlBuildId = 8.0.0.00-20190910-142437
```

the output whenever im using domain is request timeout error

Comment: Is your HTTPS server  which is mapped with domain configured with CA certificate ?? Is it a public CA certificate or self signed ?

Answer (score 0):

Please update with which MobileFirst API request is timing out.

REQUEST_TIMEOUT error will come if

> > > i.If the server is not accessible on the IP address/port specified in mfpclient.properties file.
> > >
> > > ii.When timeout is set in WLResourceRequest  and there is a delay in adapter response that is more than timeout value.
> > >
> > > iii.Having said that, the request timeout error occurs when a request made by the device does not get a response from the MobileFirst server within the stipulated timeout period. For OAuth calls, this timeout is 10 seconds.
> > >
> > > iv. Server is taking more time to respond. Check your backend logic.
> > >
> > > v. Possibilties that DNS resolution is not happening within 10 sec.

Comment: Can i know where can i configure the request timeout setting and how to increase the timeout because last week ,mobilefirst server connected successfully with no issue using domain address. But suddenly ,im facing request timeout error then i updated latest ifix on server side and cordova client side. Still im facing the time out error.

Comment: Which MobileFirst API call is timing out ?

Comment: WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() return "failed to connect the mobilefirst server" and request timeout error whenever im using domain address.

Comment: if Im using direct ip address, i successfully connected to mobilefirst server and theres no timeout error for any API.

Comment: Possibly you will have to trouble shoot why DNS resolution taking more time