# IBM MFP8 Server Responds with Request timed out using domain host

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, reverse-proxy, mobilefirst-server

*Mobile Apps and web portal are successfully connected to MFP8 server without domain host(means using MFP8 instance server Private IP)
Note: Web portal successfully connected to MFP8 server with domain host ([Web portal] > [reverse proxy:443] > [web server:80] > nodejs server:9090 /MFP] >[mfp server:9080])*

Mobile App is not connected successfully to MFP8 server with domain host ([mobile apps] > [reverse proxy:443] > [web server:80 /MFP] > [mfp server:9080])

The request from mobile App is able reached the MFP8 server using domain but the response from MFP8 server not reached to mobile apps.

IBM Mobile first server(8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201909261537)
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2019091217

logs from mobile apps:

```
[ERROR] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFailed:error:] in WLRequest.m:418 :: Status code='0' error='The request timed out.' response='(null)'
2019-10-15 12:58:49.922160+0800 Mfp8UAT[11044:5861071] WL_REQUEST
2019-10-15 12:58:49.925672+0800 UAT[11044:5873886] [] nw_connection_receive_internal_block_invoke [C6] Receive reply failed with error "Operation canceled"
2019-10-15 12:58:49.932423+0800 Mfp8UAT[11044:5861071] {"responseHeaders":{},"status":0,"responseText":"undefined","errorCode":"0","errorMsg":"The request timed out."}

2019-10-15 12:58:49.932596+0800 SebCaresMfp8UAT[11044:5873886] [ERROR] [NONE] WLAuthorizationManager.invokeAuthorizationRequest for scope RegisteredClient failed with error: 
{"responseHeaders":{},"status":0,"responseText":"undefined","errorCode":"0","errorMsg":"The request timed out."}
```

Please can anyone advise

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58213778/using-domain-mfp-8-server-return-request-time-out-using-real-mobile-device/58213888?noredirect=1#comment102804773_58213888

Answer (score 0):

Kindly verify you have given a valid port in the `mfpclient.plist` for the domain which you are trying with.

Usually, the default port for domains will be 80.

This should resolve the issue if you have given wrong port.